# MySQL only allowing Date to be stored: how to store Time as well?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I would like to store in my table a full date: year, month, day, hour, minute.

Using the date type is limiting me to year month and day only.
What should I do? I have to mention that I will select records from the db order by the full date so storing the hour and minute seperatly as strings might be a problem right?

Comment: You can use DATETIME or TIMESTAMP to have date and time in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use DATETIME instead of DATE.

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to figure this out but to change it in MySQL you have to go to the column that you are looking to change in structure. Change the Type column from DATE to DATETIME.